# Как прочитать видеофайл с внутриннего хранилища устройсва папки DCIM/Camera?

Tags: android

Какой метод нужно использовать для того чтобы в VideoView  проиграть
видео файл, который расположен  в папке устройства (Inner Storage) DCIM/Camera ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
     // Не работает
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Cars.mp4");


    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();


 }
}
```

Comment: При выборе файла через Intent к вам придет Uri, вот его и вставляйте в videoView

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Cars.mp4"));
```

Примерно так.
Но путь к карте памяти правильнее будет получать так:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```